# $K(X,Y)$ is closed in $B(X,Y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-verification

I tried to prove that the set of compact operators $K(X,Y)$ is a closed subset of the set of bounded operators $B(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces. Please can you tell me if my proof is correct?

Let $u_n$ be a sequence in $K(X,Y)$ and let $u \in B(X,Y)$ be such that $\|u-u_n\| \to 0$ (in operator norm). Let $S$ denote the unit ball in $X$. The goal is to show that $u(S)$ is totally bounded:

Let $N$ be such that $\|u-u_N\|< {\varepsilon \over 2}$. Since $u_N$ is compact the image $u_N(S)$ may be covered using finitely many  balls of radius ${\varepsilon \over 2}$. Let $y_1, \dots , y_K$ denote their centers. Then for every $i$, $y_i = u_N(s_i)$ for some $s_i \in S$. We claim that the balls $B(u(s_i), \varepsilon)$ cover $u(S)$. To see this let $y \in u(S)$. Then $y=u(s)$ for some $s \in S$. Let $i$ be such that $u_N(s) \in B(u_N(s_i), {\varepsilon \over 2})$. Then

$$ \|y-u(s_i)\|_Y = \|u(s)-u(s_i)\|_Y \le \|u(s) -u_N(s)\|_Y + \|u_N(s)-u_N(s_i)\|_Y < \varepsilon$$

Comment: The idea is right, but your last step isn't. $\lVert y-u(s_i)\rVert = \lVert u(s)-u(s_i)\rVert \neq \lVert u(s) - u_N(s_i)\rVert$ in general. Use $\varepsilon/3$ instead.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am sorry but I don't understand the mistake. I didn't write that $\|u(s)-u(s_i)\| = \|u(s)-u_N(s_i)\|$ anywhere I simply applied the triangle inequality after doing $-u_N(s) + u_N(s)$. Please could you elaborate please?

Comment: In your last chain of equalities/inequalities, you start with $\lVert y-u(s_i)\rVert = \lVert u(s) - u_N(s_i)\rVert$, but it ought to be $\lVert y-u(s_i)\rVert = \lVert u(s) - u(s_i)\rVert$. You can then estimate that by $\lVert u(s)-u_N(s)\rVert + \lVert u_N(s) - u_N(s_i)\rVert + \lVert u_N(s_i) - u(s_i)\rVert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer The $N$ was a very confusing typo, I apologize. Do you still see a mistake in my argument?

Comment: Your chain still ends at $u_N(s_i)$ on the right, you need $y = u(s) \to u_N(s) \to u_N(s_i) \to u(s_i)$. Another option is to use the balls $B_\varepsilon(u_N(s_i))$ to cover $u(S)$. Then you only need $y=u(s) \to u_N(s) \to u_N(s_i)$.